# python convert list of matrices in a single matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

From a for loop i obtain a list of matrices. Every matrix as a dimension [m*n]. i called spettri_cp1 the list of matrices. At the moment i have 12 matrix. I would like to build a single matrix with a dimension [m,12*n]. I tried with this loop but i obtain again a new list.
dimension of list spettro_cp1 = [12,224,18]

```
mat_cp1=[]  #i define the new matrix
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(18):
        frame = spettri_cp1[i,:,:] # from the list i extract the first matrix
        spettro = frame[:,j] # from the first matrix i extract the single column
mat_cp1.append(spettro) # i append all the extracted column to build the new matrix
```

what's wrong?

Comment: The indentation of the last line seems off. `mat_cp1` would just be equal to the last `spettro` value.

Comment: thank you. I also added, after the loop a command to create a matrix: mat_cp1 = np.array(mat_cp1)

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `np.concatenate(); np.reshape()` ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

m=3
n=4
listOfMatrices = [ [[random.random() for k in range(m)] for p in range(n)] for i in range(12)] #first create a list of random 12 matrix with m=3, n=4
flatList = [i for j in listOfMatrices for i in j]
flatList  = list(map(list, zip(*flatList ))) # transpose to get the desired shape
```